# Blacklist the [words] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) has been heavily discouraged since the early days of the site. A few weeks ago I manually retagged every question that used [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words), and there are currently no questions with that tag, save one question that has since been migrated.

This tag is really bad. It means nothing at all, and is only ever used by utter n00bs who have no idea what other tags to put on a question. Everybody hates it. Please make it go away forever.

**Edit** And here it is almost a year later, and I just had to squash 5 "word" tags, 4 of which were the *only* tag on the question. Can we ***please*** get this added to a permanent blacklist-with-prejudice-attached? Pretty please? --Martha

**5/31/2012** And once again, I had to kill something like 11 "words" tags, about half of which were the only tag on the question. Two of them were merged, so I can't even edit out the tag: [What is the antonyms of "capitalize"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66847/what-is-the-antonyms-of-capitalize) and [Asking question about position of a person in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65884/asking-question-about-position-of-a-person-in-a-list). I noticed that *word* is now listed as a synonym of *words*, but manifestly neither is blacklisted. Is there a reason the Powers That Be are refusing to do this?

Comment: I was tempted to add [words] to this question since it is most certainly relevant.

Comment: @MrHen The tags on the meta site are different from the tags used by the main site.

Comment: I have posted the link to this question in the moderators' chat room, pinging the person I was suggested. Now that there are not questions tagged with [tag:words], the tag can blacklisted.

Comment: I find myself wishing we could put a bounty on meta questions. What will it take to truly kill this tag? It's just as useless as [english] would be.

Comment: Suggested titles: "We don't need [words]", "[Words] are not enough".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm "[Words] are meaningless"

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - "It's only [words], but [words] are all I have, to take this tag awaaaaay".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community manager Shog9 has kindly granted our request. No more questions tagged "words" (or "word") will appear.

Comment: woo hoo! ... but... what's to stop some joker from typing it in again anyway?

Comment: @Mitch When a tag is "burninated", it's removed from all questions, but people can re-create it by typing it in again.  When a tag is "blacklisted", people can't re-create it by typing it in again.  The site won't let them.

Comment: AND THERE WAS GREAT REJOICING.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately even moderators don't have access to modify the blacklist; only devs have that ability. Otherwise I would have done this already!

Comment: Yes. I'm hoping the devs stop by and have pity on us.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: I've put in a [feature request on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125812/give-moderators-the-ability-to-manage-blacklisted-tags) - hopefully if you and many others upvote it, TPTB might change things so nohat can just sort such matters out "locally" soon!

Comment: You could make "words" a synonym for "questions-with-this-tag-are-ignored."