# Merged questions with "bad" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, merged-questions

Anent the [Blacklist the [words] tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/blacklist-the-words-tag) question, there are two questions that are tagged with the utterly useless [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words), but because they have been merged, the offending tag can't be edited out:

- [What is the antonyms of "capitalize"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66847/what-is-the-antonyms-of-capitalize)
- [Asking question about position of a person in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65884/asking-question-about-position-of-a-person-in-a-list)

Can mods do anything about this? If I understand the mechanism correctly, these questions are preventing the [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) tag from being automatically deleted, which would at least prevent *some* people from resurrecting it like some zombie. (The *real* solution is of course to nuke this tag from orbit, but there seems to be some unwillingness from TPTB to implement that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) removed on those two questions.

Comment: Danke schön! :)